# How can I add a characters at the end and at the beginning of a string list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist, webforms

I have an array with these list strings:

```
a -- b -- c 
d -- e -- f
g -- h -- i
```

I want to get this:

> (a,b,c) , (d,e,f), (g,h,i)

This is my code:

```
'I iterate through the entire list to create the string
Dim valueChain As String = ""
Dim lista As New List(Of String)
For Each item In MyArrayList
    For Each subitem In item
        valueChain += subitem.ToString + " ,"
    Next

    ' I remove the last ,
    valueChain = valueChain.TrimEnd(",")
    valueChain = "(" + valueChain + ") ,"

Next

lista.Add(valueChain)
```

But I get this:

> (((a ,b ,c) ,d ,e ,f ) ,g ,h ,i ) ,

How can I get this? :

> (a,b,c) , (d,e,f), (g,h,i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding value chain only once. Instead try to add it within the first loop and clean valueChain after this.

```
     Dim lista As New List(Of String)
          For Each item In MyArrayList
                Dim valueChain As String = ""

                For Each subitem In item
                    valueChain += subitem.ToString + ","
                Next

                valueChain = valueChain.TrimEnd(",")
                valueChain = "(" + valueChain + ")"

                lista.Add(valueChain)
            Next
```

You'll get 3 items in `lista`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to use the ampersand (`&`) concatenation operator instead of the plus (`+`), as the ampersand is made specifically for that purpose.

Now to your code. If you want it to be as compact as you've written it you should remove the space in when adding the sub items:

```
valueChain &= subitem.ToString & ","
```

Note that `ToString` isn't needed if this already is an array of `String`.

Then, you keep adding a bracket `(` before your chain for every iteration through your main array. You should append the bracket right before you start iterating through the sub items, then append the closing bracket after that:

```
For Each item In MyArrayList
    'Append the opening bracket.
valueChain &= "("
    For Each subitem In item
        valueChain &= subitem.ToString & ","
    Next

    'Remove the last comma
    valueChain = valueChain.TrimEnd(",")

    'Append the closing bracket and the comma.
    valueChain &= "), "
Next

'Remove the last comma and space.
valueChain = valueChain.TrimEnd(", ")

lista.Add(valueChain)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code gives me this result:                                                                      (a,b,c(d,e,f(g,h,i

Comment: @Esraa_92 : Really? Well I haven't tested it so I guess I will. But it should add the closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I add this:

```
Dim lista As New List(Of String)
          For Each item In MyArrayList
                Dim valueChain As String = ""

                For Each subitem In item
                    valueChain += subitem.ToString + ","
                Next

                valueChain = valueChain.TrimEnd(",")
                valueChain = "(" + valueChain + ")"

                lista.Add(valueChain)
            Next
```

And then added this to create the string:

```
Dim char As String = ""
            For i As Integer = 0 To lista.Count - 1
                char+= lista(i) + " ,"
            Next

            'I remove the last ,
            char= char.TrimEnd(",")
```